# Ubuntu Touch App File Type

Tags: application-development

Hello I was wondering what type of app files you can upload to the ubuntu touch app store

It is apk files?

Answer (score 2):

No , It is click apps , more details [here](http://developer.ubuntu.com/publish/apps/packaging-click-apps/)